# Chromium only plays the commersials, not the content

Tags: video, chromium, snap

I'm trying to play content from the Dutch public broadcaster NPO (https://www.npostart.nl) in Chromium (Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)). As the title says, the commercials - loaded and shown in a player before the content starts - are played fine. After the commercials are finished, I get the content player with an loading spinner continuing ever after.

In Firefox  the content plays just fine after the ads are done. Checking the inspector, it seems it's an HTML5 video. Not sure why the ads would be, and the content itself wouldn't play. Following [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/dutch-public-broadcast-npo-html5-video%27s-fail-to-play-4175621551/) I installed FFmpeg, but that didn't help.

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and added Chromium via the store (which takes the snap by default). Anybody a clue on how to solve or start debugging this?